# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(2n-1)x = \frac {\sin(2Nx)}{2\sin(x)} $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am studying Fourier analysis and have been given the following question:

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(2n-1)x = \frac {\sin(2Nx)}{2\sin(x)} $$

I used the formula for a finite geometric sum and Euler's formula to get to the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos(2n-1)x = Re (\sum_{n=1}^{N} e^{i(2n-1)x}) = Re (\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{i(2n+1)x}) = Re (e^{ix} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (e^{i2x})^n) = .... = Re(\frac{i}{2 \sin{x}}(1-e^{i2xN}))$

I have been stuck here for a while and am unsure how to get to the required $\frac {\sin(2Nx)}{2\sin(x)}$.

What do I do next?

Comment: You're almost there. Hint: $i(1-e^{2ixN}) = \sin(2Nx) + i(1-\cos(2Nx))$

Comment: The angles are in AP with common Difference 2x.. so you can just use the formula of cosine summation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard trick: factor out $\mathrm e^{iNx}$:
$$ i(1-\mathrm e^{2iNx})=i\mathrm e^{iNx}(\mathrm e^{-iNx}-\mathrm e^{iNx})=\mathrm e^{iNx}\frac{\mathrm e^{iNx}-\mathrm e^{-iNx}}i=2\sin x\,\mathrm e^{iNx},$$
whence
$$\operatorname{Re}\Bigl(\frac{i}{2 \sin{x}}(1-\mathrm e^{i2xN})\Bigr)=
\operatorname{Re}\Bigl(\frac{2\sin Nx\:\mathrm e^{ixN}}{2 \sin Nx}\Bigr)
=\frac{2\sin Nx\cos Nx}{2\sin x}.$$

Comment: I'm not the "struck" downvoter :-).

Comment: @bernard i understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$2\sin(a)\cos(b)
= \sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)
$,
$2\sin(x)\cos((2n-1)x)
= \sin(2nx)+\sin(-(2n-2)x)
= \sin(2nx)-\sin((2n-2)x)
$,
so you get a telescoping sum.